# css a:hover limiting

Tags: hover

I've got this codes:

```
ul
{ list-style-type: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:link,a:visited
{ display: block;
  width: 240px;
  background: transparent url(./style/black2.jpg) ;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #ffffff
}

a:hover,a:active
{ background: transparent;
  color: #000000
}
```

and this one

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wbdemo/pages/abc.php"><h99>Home<h99/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h99>Home</h99></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h99>Home</h99/></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><h99>Home</h99/></a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><h99>Home</h99/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Everything that has got links "hovers" now.
I want to limit a:hover just to the menu section and seperate it from the rest.

Comment: Add a limitation to your CSS selectors to only work under your menu section (via class or id)

Comment: Just wanted to drop a line the "h99" HTML element you're using doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style **only** the links which are inside `<ul>` element, you should code it like this:

```
ul a:hover {
    /* here goes the styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and effective!

Answer (score 1):

Use a more specific selector then:

```
ul a
{ 
style
}
```

If you can give the menu an ID:

```
<ul id="menu">
```

Then you can do:

```
ul#menu a
```